# What type of circuit these vintage 1VNP tantalum caps were used in?

Tags: capacitor, vintage

In my junk box I have several capacitors that are marked 1VNP, which I assume means a voltage rating of 1VDC Non Polarized. Looking around online it would appear these are solid tantalum capacitors, maybe.

I'm curious as to what type of circuit could use a cap with such a low voltage rating.

I have read that tantalum caps are noted for high density, low ESR, and high stability, but they are also notorious for high failure rate from even small overvoltages.

These are several decades old, made before circuits were miniaturized as we know today. I have always thought of electrolytics (and tantalums) were mainly used in power supply circuits and other bypass functions, but can't think of how a 1V rated cap could be used in a circuit.

[image]

Comment: Tantalum capacitors are not usually tubular. I think these are aluminum electrolytics. I would be surprised if these are actually rated at 1 V; there are a couple common codes for capacitors that might produce the sequence 1V without it meaning 1 volt. Incidentally, the "6225" on that last capacitor tells us when it was made: the 25th week of 1962.

Comment: What are the physical dimensions of the capacitors? I'm just curious; I don't know if that will help to identify them.

Comment: They are approx 2" long and 3/8" diameter. Several of them are Mallory brand. Thanks for dating them, I wasn't sure how to read that.

Comment: I have seen tubular tantalum caps. You can tell if they are aluminum or tantalum by their weight, tantalums are much heavier.